# Cloud Shell has been disabled due to a Terms of Service violation

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I just started using the GCP for learning cloud technologies and literally the second day I got this error:

```
user@PC:~$ gcloud alpha cloud-shell ssh

Starting your Cloud Shell machine...
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.cloud-shell.ssh) PERMISSION_DENIED: Cloud Shell has been disabled due to a Terms of Service violation
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.shell.v1alpha1.CloudShellErrorDetails   code: CLOUD_SHELL_DISABLED
```

Is there a way to learn exactly which rule(s) I violated? Before the shell was blocked, during the ssh sessions, I was disconnecting pretty frequently so I added these lines to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on my local computer:

```
Host *

    TCPKeepAlive yes
    ServerAliveInterval 120
```

Could this be the cause of my violation?

Thanks

Comment: Stop mining Bitcoin on GCP

Comment: What made you think that I was mining Bitcoin? I don't know how but `gcloud` won't throw that error anymore. The day before I got blocked, all I did was follow the second chapter of "Data Science on the Google Cloud Platform" by Valliappa Lakshmanan (which includes cloning a repository, fetching few mb of data from an api, simple bash and py scripts and writing to storage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons for which your account could be disabled based on “Terms of Service” violations. [1]

- Cloud Shell inactivity
- Non-interactive usage, such as inactive sessions
- Surpassed weekly usage limits
- Exceeded Service limits

To know more in your case, you can fill a private issue tracker describing in detail the issue [2]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations

[2] https://issuetracker.google.com/components/491139/manage#basic